# Difference between a simple variable i and *(&i);

Tags: c, pointers, variables

I have the following C program:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    printf("Simple value of i = %d", i);
    printf("\nPointer value of i = %d", *(&i));
    return 0;
}
```

Both of the `printf()` will print the same thing, which is 5. As per my understanding `&` is being used for address value and  `*` is used to pick the value on that address.

My question is: Why do we need `*(&i)` if the same thing can be achieved by a simple `i` variable?

Comment: dereferencing a reference does nothing

Comment: *"why we need *(&i)"* Who said that you need to do that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It does a few things, at the least dereferencing and referencing ;-) But I got what you meant :-)...

Comment: @Bathsheba while I don't disagree with you, probably the point you're mentioning require a better question (code sample, at least) which actually causes the case y'll are pointing to. :) Otherwise, as it's current face value, the answer is, "well, you don't."

Comment: @SouravGhosh: To my mind there's nothing wrong with an OP unwittingly stumbling on an interesting topic.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's what I also said in the starting words of my comment, and I, for one, would like to see the question updated with the relevant part which helps us all in future. :)

Comment: It’s important to note that, while it’s equivalent in C (excepting side-effects mentioned by Bathsheba), it is *not necessarily the same in C++* because the `operator*` can be overloaded.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is why we need *(&i) if same thing can be achieved with simple i variable?

Well, you don't need it.

The expression `*(&i)` is equivalent to `i`.

[6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2) says:

> The unary * operator denotes indirection. If the operand points to a function, the result is a function designator; if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object. If the operand has type ''pointer to type'', the result has type ''type''. If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.102)

And the footnote:

> Thus, &*E is equivalent to E (even if E is a null pointer), and &(E1[E2]) to ((E1)+(E2)). [..]

The C standard allows a compiler to transform the code in anyway as long as the *observable behaviour* (see: [5.1.2.3 Program execution](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p6)) is same.
So the statement:

```
printf("\nPointer value of i = %d", *(&i));
```

can be, in theory, transformed into:

```
printf("\nPointer value of i = %d", i);
```

by a compiler without violating C standard.

Answer (score 6):

`*(&i)` is **almost** exactly the same as `i`.

A compiler is allowed to optimise it out, but do note that it is not allowed to do that if there is a side-effect of the address of `i` being taken (it can no longer be stored solely in a CPU register for example).

Comment: nice answer. Can you elaborate on the side effect thing? related to volatile or such?

Comment: I'm racking my brains on conjuring an example. Am failing miserably currently.

Comment: I can't find relevant information on standard. Taking address can prevent register storage, but I can't find proof that optimizing out `&` itself would be restricted.

Comment: @user694733 The difference is that if `i` had not been initialized, the behavior would be undefined when using `i`, while `*(&i)` merely gets you an indeterminate value, which as far as I can tell is not UB by itself, contrarily to what J.2 is saying, unless `int` has trap representations. This buried at the end of 6.3.2.1§2: "If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class [...], and that object is uninitialized [...], the behavior is undefined."